# C# Multithreading Pass by value or reference?

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, memory-management, pass-by-reference

I saw a piece of code online that states that calling a thread like this causes non-deterministic output "0223557799" or something  of this kind.(You get the point)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   new Thread (() => Console.Write (i)).Start();
```

This is the reason given for this:

*"The problem is that the i variable refers to the same memory location throughout the loop’s lifetime. Therefore, each thread calls Console.Write on a variable whose value may change as it is running!"*

But, conventionally speaking when the argument is passed by value - each new Thread call should send **i** its incremental order right ? Only if values are pass by reference the above mentioned reason holds good. So, in C# Multi-Threading, are the values pass by reference ?

I'm new to C#,Please understand if the question is naive.

Comment: int temp = i; place it inside loop and pass temp,slaks is right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is more than one problem here.  It certainly starts with the for() loop variable capture problem, described in this [blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one).  This tends to produce "10" as the output, but there's no guarantee this happens since a thread may execute while the loop is still being iterated.

But the program also suffers for a core threading problem, there's no guarantee whatsoever that the threads will call Console.Write() in the expected order.  It is merely *likely*, but one thread may race ahead of another and acquire the lock that protects the console. A problem known as a "[threading race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)".

Comment: The change in C# 5 only applied to foreach loops, not for loops.

Answer (score 11):

Your program is equivalent to the following program:

```
class Locals
{
    public int i;
    public void M() { Console.Write(this.i);
}

...
Locals locals = new Locals();
for (locals.i = 0; locals.i < 10; locals.i++)
  new Thread (locals.M).Start();
```

Now is it clear why you get the results you do?  It is not `i` that is being passed by value; rather it is `locals` that is being passed *by reference* to each thread. Each thread is *sharing* `locals.i` and therefore can see the *current* value of `locals.i`, not the value that `i` was when the thread was created.